# Kubernetes Cronjob using temporary Volume in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm writing a CronJob which needs to create a Persistent Volume when it starts, attach it to the container, and once the job is done it should destroy it again.

I was reading through the reclaim policies of PVCs and PVs, but I can't find a nice way to do that without having to script the creation / deletion of the PVCs at the beginning / end of the job.

Comment: Have you considered `emptyDir` volume type instead?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google Wouldn't that put the data on the node's disk? I need quite a lot of temporary storage for that cronjob, it would fill up the node's disk. That cronjob only runs once every week, so i wouldn't want to have to grow the node's disk to accomodate for it, because the extra space won't be used during most of the time

Comment: EmptyDir is deleted once pod goes away.